# check per row if the id of a row exists as an id in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Right now I have three mysql tables. I have to list all the people from `people` in a table. Next to this it shows there interests, here is the sql for it.

```
SELECT *,(
           SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(interest_id SEPARATOR ",")
           FROM cat_people_interests
           WHERE person_id = people.id
         ) AS cat_interests
FROM people
WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT person_id
    FROM cat_interests
)
ORDER BY lastname, firstname);
```

SCHEMA

```
`people` { int:id, varchar:name }
`cat_people_interests` { int:interest_id, int:person_id }
`cat_interests` { int:id, varchar:name }
`alternate_meow_pull` { int:person_id, int:meow_id, int:dataetc, int:dataetc2 }
```

So this gives me the ability to pull there names, and all interests.

How can I alter or add to this to check per row if the id of a person exists as a person_id in another table (alternate_meow_pull)? What I would do personally is just check with a mysql query on each row, but I'm sure there is a faster and more terse way. I want to get the result regardless of if the person exists in alternate_meow_pull by the way.

So when I loop through this result, I want to be able to print the name, id, all interests that correlate with person, and any data that happens to be in alternate_meow_pull that correlate with person.

Comment: can you add sample records and desired output?

Comment: shouldn't "firstname')" be "firstname)" in the order by clause

Comment: @Michael You're correct, fixed & thanks.

Comment: @JohnWoo I've added some more information regarding it, thanks.

Comment: You have also error here "'showinterest_id'", shouldn't it be part of a string e.g. ('.clean($_POST[showinterest_id]).'), i think you meant WHERE interest_id = showinterest_id, (and showinterest is some type of integer inputed from outside)?

Comment: @Michael Thanks, the code above is part of a brached out system, if something is sent to it it will choose to display only those with that interest, otherwise it shows all interests, I was a bit sloppy copying it.

Comment: Please Re-check your whole statement, it seems that it contains many errors , i don't know how you are able to compare int with string, etc... i advice you to post a working version, since it is only confuses us while trying to supply you an answer!

Comment: @jett: if you got an answer for your question, accept it, otherwise edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
SELECT  a.name, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) InterestList
FROM    people  a
        INNER JOIN cat_people_interest c
            ON a.ID = c.person_ID
        INNER JOIN cat_interests b
            ON b.id = c.interest_ID 
        INNER JOIN alternate_meow_pull d
            ON a.person_ID = d.person_id
WHERE   b.interest_id = '$_POST['showinterest_id']'
GROUP BY a.name
```

only the names of person that their `ID` is present on `alternate_meow_pull` will only be shown.

Comment: How can I change this to make alternate_meow_pull optional? Some people wont have any cat_interests and some people wont be on alternate_cat_pull, I'd still like to draw there name with empty results for interests and alternate_cat_pulls ?

Comment: @jett use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT people.id, people.name
 FROM people,cat_people_interests as c,cat_interests as i, alternate_meow_pull as m
 WHERE people.id = c.person_id or people.id = i.id or people.id = m.person_id
```